# Need help creating this responsive Stacked Card look with Grid CSS. Code below

Tags: css, user-interface, frontend, grid, css-grid

I'm trying to achieve this stacked card container using CSS Grid. I know Grid can be hard being that there is so much to know about their properties. The final stacked card will be 3 rows and be responsive hopefully using

```
`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10rem, 1fr));`
```

[final stacked card look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wPz8.png)

I want to however create an illusion using Grid instead of using display: absolute and using top/bottom or negative margins. My idea is to use Grid to create this breakdown here:

[Illusion of stacked card using grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtjCE.png)

Does anyone know how I can achieve the second picture (illusion of the cards being stacked) using the Grid container? Where the side card is on the right and the bottom card is at the bottom of the Main Card?

Below is my start up code, I am using React.js:

```
<div className={classes.outerCard}>
          <div className={classes.mainCard}>
            <h2 className={classes.title}>{title}</h2>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.sideCard}></div>
          <div className={classes.bottomCard}>
            <h5 className={classes.subtitle}>{subtitle}</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Please let me know your ideas or Grid knowledge! Anything will be helpful. It seems like

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
```

is the best option to keep it being responsive without any media queries, that will set up a grid container that has a flexible number of columns in this case keep 3 columns as long as possible before breaking into 2 columns and then eventually just a row for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

With grid you will need to specify the start/end columns and rows for all of the divs because of the way they have jutting edges. The minimum number of rows and columns you will need is 5 each. I set estimated fixed column and rough dimensions to match your image; you'll have to adjust in order for them to be responsive.

```css
.outerCard {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 20px 200px 30px 60px;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 40px 300px repeat(2, 40px);
  width: 360px;
  background-color: LightGoldenRodYellow;
}

.mainCard { 
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 4 / 4;
  background-color: LightGrey;
}

.sideCard { 
  grid-area: 3 / 4 / 4 / 5;
  background-color: LightPink;
}

.bottomCard { 
  grid-area: 4 / 3 / 5 / 5;
  background-color: LightCoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerCard">
  <div class="mainCard">
    <h2 class="title">title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="sideCard"></div>
  <div class="bottomCard">
    <h5 class="subtitle">subtitle</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```